# calling keys from multidimensional array in a loop php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looping though my multidimensional array. $array1

```
for($index=0; $index < count($anotherArray); $index++){

  '"data-example "' = . $array1[$index]["Number"].
```

One of the indexes for array1 looks like this, all have similar formats

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array 
      ( [Date] => 1991-04-20
        [Number] => 24309832 
        [Color] => Green  
      )
   [1] => Array 
      ( [Date] => 1817-11-05
        [Number] => 9843 
        [Color] => Red  
      )
   [2] => Array 
      ( [Date] => 1500-09-22 
        [Number] => 45
        [Color] => Blue  
      )
```

I am trying to pass all the "Number" fields as a javascript data element. 
I am getting an error of

```
Notice: Undefined index: Number
```

Comment: Make sure what you should use: `$anotherArray` or `$array1`.

Comment: $anotherarray really has nothing to do with the problem its just taking a count.

Comment: Provide the full code. Why is this tagged as JS? I can't see any in JS in the question.

Comment: what is the value of `count($anotherArray)`?. If it's ever higher than `count($array1);` then you'll have a problem. You can check easily on which iteration of the loop the error occurs by echoing the value of `$index` each time.

Comment: $anotherArray and $array1 are the same in count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you should not use a different array for a count. How can you be certain that `$anotherArray` and `$array1` will always contain the exact same number of items?

There are several ways you can fix your code.

Option 1 - use `isset` to make sure the indexes from the two arrays match:

```
for($index=0; $index < count($anotherArray); $index++){

    if (isset($array1[$index])) {
        '"data-example "' = . $array1[$index]["Number"].        
    }
```

Option 2 - use `$array1` when counting:

```
for($index=0; $index < count($array1); $index++){

    '"data-example "' = . $array1[$index]["Number"].
```

Option 3 - switch to a `foreach` so you don't need to worry about the index:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $data) {

    '"data-example "' = . $data["Number"].
```

Since you don't include your full code I'll leave it up to you to decide the best implementation.